# Concatenate elements of a char array and strings in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm probably over thinking this, but this is not coming out the way I expect. I've searched google, I've searched stackoverflow. Please Help.

Here are some variables for testing, and the invocation of a function:

```
$SQL_FirstName = "PowerShell";
$SQL_LastName = "CreateUser";
$SQL_Office = "TEST";
$SQL_IsAdmin = $true;     
Create_User($SQL_FirstName.ToLower(), $SQL_LastName.ToLower(), $SQL_Office, $SQL_IsAdmin);
```

Here is the function, not much there yet:

```
Function Create_User([string]$FirstName, [string]$LastName, $Office, $IsAdmin)
{
    $FirstNameCharArray = [char[]]$FirstName;
    $UserName = [string]$FirstNameCharArray[0] + $LastName;
    Write-Host $UserName;
}
```

Now I expect the output to be "pcreateuser".  But it's not. I have tried casting different things, I have tried surrounding my variables with $(). I have tried using the + symbol and not using the + symbol. I have tried smashing the variables right up against each other. Every single time it just outputs "p".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of how you are calling the function. You are not supposed to use brackets for function calls nor use commas to separate the parameters (unless you are sending array values on purpose or subexpressions). You have passed it a single array of those elements.

```
Create_User $SQL_FirstName.ToLower() $SQL_LastName.ToLower() $SQL_Office $SQL_IsAdmin
```

In your function call your sent an array to `$firstname` which was casted as a string "powershell createuser TEST True". The other parameters would have been blank. Hence your output.

They work just the same as cmdlet calls. Just use spaces to separate the parameters and their values.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" -Path "C:\temp"
```

**String to char array**

For what it is worth you don't need to cast the string as a char array. You can just use array notation directly on the string.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> [string]"Bagels"[0]
B
```

Heck you don't even need to cast it `"Bagels"[0]`

Comment: Apparently switching back and forth between several languages can cause stupid mistakes.